# How to import modules in Python framework with multiple subfolder

Tags: python, python-import

My question might have discussed in earlier posts too, but couldn't get proper answer applicable for my scenario. Hence posting it as a new query.
I have multiple sub-folders where module tries to import modules present across multiple subfolders.

Folder Structure:

```
main
|-- lib
|   |-- lib1.py
|   |-- lib2.py
|   `-- lib3.py
|-- common
|   |-- lib4.py
|-- tests
|   |--folder1
|       |-- script1.py
|       |-- folder2
|           |-- script2.py
|   |--scriptA.py
|   `--scriptB.py
```

Use case/Requirements:

1. script1 & script2  import functions from  module lib1.py.
2. lib1 wants to import functions from lib2.py & lib3.py
3. lib4.py import funtions from lib1 & lib2

I tried adding blank `__init__.py` in root folder (main) and the all other subfolders. But couldn't get this working. Ending up with 'ModuleNotFound' error.

Comment: Its not `init.py` , it is `__init__.py` file.

Comment: Put the scripts you run in `main` and add a `__init__.py` to all folders except `main`. Then you can import like `from lib.lib1 import ...`.

Comment: Refer to the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50194143/10907391) for full details of how to structure a python package

Comment: @KlausD. The script to be run are available in folder tests. Say Script1.py

Comment: The trick is to move them.

Comment: @DanBrezeanu, i did follow the link, but it doesn't resolve my issue.  Lib2.py is trying to import lib3 but when i execute it fails with ModuleNotFound:lib3

Answer (score 1):

You need blank `__init__.py` files, not `init.py`. See the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages) for more info.